# Why does Chrome use different fonts with the same CSS?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I have a `span` and an `input` element that share the same CSS definition for font. Why does Chrome use different fonts for them? How would I fix this issue?

### [image: Input element inspected]

[image: Span element inspected]

My objective is to make them look exactly the same in IE9, Chrome and FF.

---

CSS definitions (FIXED), if they still matter.

```
* {
    font-family: Verdana,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; /* Moving here fixed it */
}
body {
    /*font-family: Verdana,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; -- This caused the issue*/
    font-size: .8em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
}
.button 
{
    text-align:center;
    min-width:80px;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    background-color:#4A8CF6;
    color:#FFF;
    padding:4px;
    margin:1px;
    border:0;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-size: .8em;
}
```

---

*Solution*

The problem was that the span elements inherited from my CSS definition for body and the input elements didn't. I had defined the font in my CSS with `body { font-family:...; }` like my computed results show and I thought that using `display: inline-block;` would force both of them to inherit the font from body but it did not.

The solution was to switch to using `* { font-family:...; }` for the font definitions. The button and clickable classes simply defined sizes and colors and such.

Comment: What is the CSS definition for the `clickable_button` class?

Comment: @TomWalters I thought the Computed Styles was enough to see the CSS, sorry. I solved, accepted and added a solution explanation based on your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to literally specify input elements if you want them to have the same font like so:

```
/* Or input[type=submit] depending on your needs */
span, input { 
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif; /* Your font here */
}
```

Otherwise the browser uses the default values as your question shows. You're looking under **Computed Styles** which shows that Chrome has decided the values for you as you haven't specified them.

Comment: Thanks. The issue was CSS inheritance. I thought my `inline-block` definition made `input` inherit from `body` but it did not. I added a solution to the question

Answer (score -2):

You should apply CSS reset rules in the beginning of your style sheet. Its purpose is to make all elements have the same look in all browser.

Examples:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Related question which can be useful too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset